# Widget pending intents not updating

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget showing 10 images. On click on one of that images, it opens an activity showing some information corresponding to that image. The data is stored in an sqlite datebase.

Every week, these images change (its a pool of > 100 different objects, each week another subset of those is shown).

My onUpdate method looks like this:

```
List<Champion> champions = // a list of 10 champions out of 100 fetched from db
int[] imageIds = // drawable ids for the 10 champions

// creating the pending intents
PendingIntent[] pIntents = new PendingIntent[champions.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < champions.size(); i++)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChampionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ChampionActivity.KEY_ID, champions.get(i).getChampionId());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pIntents[i] = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, intent, 0);
}

// updating widgets with the new images and intents
for(int widgetId : appWidgetIds)
{
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(
                          context.getPackageName(),
                          R.layout.widget
                       );
    for(int i = 0; i < imageViewIds.length; i++)
    {
        view.setImageViewResource(imageViewIds[i], imageIds[i]);
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(imageViewIds[i], pIntents[i]);
    }
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, view);
}
```

This widget is set to update itself every 30 minutes. Update of the images works fine, but somehow the pending intents seems to not be updated.

Example:
- User adds the widget to his homescreen when champion A is shown.
- After 30 minutes, champion A is replaced with champion B, the image is updated accordingly
- A click on champion B still leads the user to champion A (intent extra is id of A, not id ob B)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to update the extra data in a PendingIntent if it already exists, you can use [PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) flag. Since you need only one pending intent active at a time, it is more appropriate. Remember to pass same request code. The request code can be `appWidgetId` to make it unique in case of multiple instances. [Thanks to @shoerat for pinpointing the issue].  From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT):

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
>   then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new
>   Intent. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int),
>   getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int,
>   Intent, int).
>
> This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras
>   change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous
>   PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if
>   they are not explicitly given to it.

Here is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChampionActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
pIntents[i] = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: +1: this seems to be a more appropriate way of handling the problem. However, I am wondering whether using a fixed request code causes inconsistency when there are multiple widgets?

Comment: @shoerat Thanks for bringing up the issue, You are right. In case of multiple instances, `appWidgetId` can be used. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common mistake, i.e., your problem is at this line:

```
pIntents[i] = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, intent, 0);
```

Specifically, the problem is with the [`requestCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29): it is constant for the lifetime of the widget. Therefore, platform fails to recognize new `Intent` as a "new" and will deliver the same (i.e., the first) `PendingIntent` all the time. You need to use new request code if you want a new `Intent` delivered. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> ... it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

What's the return value type for `champions.get(i).getChampionId()`? That looks like a good candidate to use as request code, if that's an `int`. So, using

```
pIntents[i] = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, champions.get(i).getChampionId(), intent, 0);
```

would probably fix the problem.

Hope this helps.